# High Charts tooltip crosshair issues in angular

Tags: highcharts

I have two series data but on hovering I am able to get only one series data on the label.
Is it possible to have both data on label on hovering in x-axis?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

[Label has Series 1:176 and I want along with that Series 2:71.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaU9n.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `tooltip.shared` parameter equal to true. Then all of defined series should be visible in tooltip.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/L0hg2c6r/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared